# Getting key prop warning in React, even though key is set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## Problem

I'm getting this warning:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of EventsTable. See [fb.me/react-warning-keys](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) for more information.
>
> react-runtime-dev.js?8fefd85d334323f8baa58410bac59b2a7f426ea7:21998 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of Event. See [fb.me/react-warning-keys](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) for more information.

### Source

This is `EventsTable`:

```
EventsTable = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'EventsTable',

  render() {
    console.dir(this.props.list);

    return (
      <table className="events-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {_.keys(this.props.list[0]).map(function (key) {
              if (key !== 'attributes') {
                return <th>{key}</th>;
              }
            })}
         </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          {this.props.list.map(function (row) {
            return (
              <Event key={row.WhatId} data={row} />
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
});
```

This is `Event`:

```js
Event = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Event',

  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        {_.keys(this.props.data).map((x) => {
          if (x !== 'attributes')
            return <td>{this.props.data[x]}</td>;
        })}
      </tr>
    )
  }
});
```

### Question

Clearly I've got the `key` prop on the `<Event />` component. And I'm following the convention that you're supposed to include `key` on the component, not on the HTML itself (in other words, HTML tags within the `Event` component). Per the official React docs:

> The key should always be supplied directly to the components in the array, not to the container HTML child of each component in the array:

I'm severely confused. Why am I getting warnings?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have you tried adding a `key` to the `<th>` tag?

```
         <tr>
            {_.keys(this.props.list[0]).map(function (key) {
              if (key !== 'attributes') {
                return <th key={key}>{key}</th>;
              }
            })}
         </tr>
```

Comment: But don't the React docs say *not* to put `key` on the HTML tag? See [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children)

Comment: My understanding of that has always been that if you are iterating over component that generates HTML, the key should be on the component.  In your case, though, you aren't using a component to generate the th tags, so it may be valid in this case.

Comment: So I added the key as you suggested, and that worked. And then I went into the `Event` component and changed that to `return <td key={x}>{this.props.data[x]}</td>` and that got rid of that warning. I don't know if I'm using the key correctly. In that case, it's just returning 0, 1, 2, etc for each TD cell. That won't be unique across the whole DOM.

Comment: I think you can leave the `key` on the `Event` component, no?  Did you try that?

Comment: I did leave the key on `<Event />` and I still got a warning for the `Event` component since it's iterating as well.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  That is strange.  Seems overkill, but what if you made the `<th>` tags a component also and put `key` on that?

Comment: Putting the key on the `<td>` works. It may not be ideal..but I can always refactor later. Your answer definitely helped, thanks!

Answer (score 37):

I ended up solving it when I realized because I had a `<React.Fragment>` which also needs a unique key.

Comment: I also just want to add to this. I had a: <></> instead of React.Fragment. I added replaced the <></> with <React.Fragment key={yourKeyHere}></React.Fragment> and all is working now w/ no warnings.

Comment: This was my issue - tried @ChrisAdams solution and it worked. Thanks! Would have never caught this

Comment: Putting <></> this is just a bad idea because it wont show error at all if you use <Fragment> then it shows you the error huh

Comment: Oh my gosh this is absurd. Thank you!

Comment: Kind of a necro, but I had a very similar problem, and I was able to solve it when I moved the key prop to the outermost element of the component. It seems that it needs to be there in order for React to recognize it.

Answer (score 19):

## tl;dr

Every time you render a list (use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), add a unique `key` attribute to the list elements (the topmost or "root" element returned from `map`'s callback):

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.data.map( element => {
         // Place the key on to the returned "root" element.
         // Also, in real life this should be a separate component...
         return <div key={element.id}>
           <span>Id (Name): </span>
           <span>{element.id} </span>
           <span>({element.name})</span>
         </div>;
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

## Explanation

### Understanding keys in React

The official [Lists and Keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html) documentation shows how you should work with lists and the [linked reconciliations doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) tells the whys.

Basically when React rerenders a component it runs a diff algorithm that finds out what changed between the new and the previous version of the list. Comparison is not always trivial, but if there is a unique key in each element, it can be clearly identified what has changed. See the [example in the doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children):

```html
<!-- previous -->
<ul>
  <li key="2015">Duke</li>
  <li key="2016">Villanova</li>
</ul>

<!-- new -->    
<ul>
  <li key="2014">Connecticut</li>
  <li key="2015">Duke</li>
  <li key="2016">Villanova</li>
</ul>
```

It is clear that a new element with the key `2014` was added, since we have all the other keys and those weren't changed. Without the keys this would be obscure.

#### Selecting a proper key

From now it is easy to see:

- Why it is important that the **key should be unique but only between the siblings** in the list, because the comparison happens only within the given list's previous and new elements.
- The **key should remain the same for the same element** between the previous and the new version, otherwise we would compare different elements and wouldn't be able to track change. That is why it is advised to use the id of the resource or (if it doesn't have one) some other data that is unique to the element, and why you shouldn't use things like `Math.random()`.

### Placing `key` attribute on components

The convention that you should place the `key` attribute to a component is more of a good practice, because when you iterate a list and want to render an element, that clearly indicates that you should organize that code to a separate component.

### Setting the `key` attribute in the loop

The statement you quoted from the docs:

> The key should always be supplied directly to the components in the array, not to the container HTML child of each component in the array:

Means that if you render components in a loop, then you should set the `key` attribute of the component in the loop, like you did it in your `EventsTable` component:

```js
{this.props.list.map(function (row) {
  return (
    <Event key={row.WhatId} data={row} />
  );
})}
```

The wrong way is to pass it down to the component where it would set the `key` on itself:

```js
Event = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Event',
  render() {
    // Don't do this!
    return (
      <tr key={this.props.data.WhatId}>
        {_.keys(this.props.data).map((x) => {
```

There is another good example for this [in this article](http://revelry.co/dynamic-child-components-with-react/).

Answer (score 12):

Check if variable that you pass to `key` is defined, because if it's `undefined` then error will be same, but it looks like code should work.

Comment: Exactly! It's very easy to miss when using eg `someId` when the real value has eg. `someID`. And even more strange is that `PropTypes` does not "comment" on that either.

Answer (score 3):

I had the problems too, and fixed it after follwing [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js).

like:

```
{_data.map(function(object, i){
     return <div className={"row"} key={i}> 
           {[ object.name ,
      <b className="fosfo" key={i}> {object.city} </b> , // remove the key
          object.age
      ]}
</div>; 
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix for this is to create a separate component for the items you're mapping and add the key to that component.

Create a new component above your existing component (or link to it your call).

```
const TableDataComponent = ({ k }) => {
   return (
     <th>{k}</th>
   )
}
```

Then in your code add that component with your key:

```
<tr>
    {arr.map((k) => {
      return <TableDataComponent key={k._id} k={k} />
    })}
</tr>
```