# React key in li

Tags: reactjs

I have a warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
But I used a key.
This is my code:

```
return (
  <li onClick={this.handleOnMarkAsCompleted} key={Date.now()}>
    { completed ? <b>{value}</b> : value }
  </li>
)
```

Any Ideas? Why doe it happen?

Comment: I guess it's in a wrong place. the list component that renders these li-s should pass key to each li.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting key prop warning in React, even though key is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256492/getting-key-prop-warning-in-react-even-though-key-is-set)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 5):

consider these two examples:

```
const Item = ({ i }) => <li key={i}>li</li>;
const List = ({ data }) => <ul>{data.map((_, i) => <Item i={i} />)}</ul>;
```

in this case, you'd get:

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
```

because `li` is not an array item. it's inside of `Item` which is an array item.

So key on `Item` would eliminate the problem:

```
const Item = ({ i }) => <li key={i}>li</li>;
const List = ({ data }) => <ul>{data.map((_, i) => <Item key={i} />)}</ul>;
```

code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/oojwjq0lj6

---

from [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys):

> Keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array.
>
> For example, if you extract a `ListItem` component, you should keep the
>   key on the `<ListItem />` elements in the array rather than on the `<li>`
>   element in the `ListItem` itself.

---

a note regarding use of `Date.now()`:

> Keys should be stable, predictable, and unique. Unstable keys (like
>   those produced by Math.random()) will cause many component instances
>   and DOM nodes to be unnecessarily recreated, which can cause
>   performance degradation and lost state in child components.

Comment: Array index as a key is generally a bad idea since array can be sorted/filtered/altered then index associated to items does not map anymore leading to same trouble as you mention for unstable keys.

Answer (score 1):

Date.now() generates current time UNIX timestamp which is the same every time (in the second which all items are rendered). Key neeeds to be unique, as described in the error. Add some kind of id or (if no alternative is possible) an iterator.

Comment: I tried with Math.random(), could you advise something?

Comment: Can you update the question with the whole snippet of code? Where is this return used, is it in a map function?

Answer (score 0):

As per ReactJS docs, Keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array.
Example of Correct key usage.

```
function ListItem(props) {
  // Correct! There is no need to specify the key here:
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function NumberList(props) {
  const numbers = props.numbers;
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    // Correct! Key should be specified inside the array.
    <ListItem key={number.toString()}
              value={number} />

  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList numbers={numbers} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[Try it on codepen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ZXeOGM?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the key prop at the parent of this component. Lets suppose your component is named TaskItem, and the component in which you are using it is called TaskItems:

```js
 const TaskItems = (props) => {
    return (
    <ul>
      {props.items.map((itemElement) => (
        <TaskItem
          key={itemElement.id}
        ></TaskItem>
      ))}
    </ul>
    );
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use index of array or keys of object row

Date.now is duplicate

Comment: is a duplicate of what? btw using array indices as keys is not recommended.