# How do I loop over an object and render them as <li></li>:<li><li>

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, jsx

I have fetched a particular object from express endpoint and I have gotten this on the console
[image]

I how do I map it in such a way that it will return a jsx that looks like

```
<li>keys</li> : <li>values</li>
```

eg
Company: DML

Comment: I suggest you group the `<li>`'s, for example: `<li><strong>keys:</strong>values</li> `

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487382/react-key-in-li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` with `map` in you React `render` function

```
Object.entries(yourObj).map(([key, value]) => {
    return <li key={key}>{key} : {value}></li>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I stored the value in the state for this example, but you may store yours differently.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8cry43vt/2/)

```
<ul>
    { Object.entries(this.state.data).map(([key, value]) => <li key={key}>{key}: {value}</li>) }
</ul>
```

The key={key} prop will prevent the "Each child in a list should have a unique key prop" warning.